# Query with wildcard and dot not matching data with Oracle Text index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

When using the wildcard character in combination with a dot in a text search, my query does not find the matching row.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE( ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ITEM_NUMBER) VALUES ('1234.1234');
create index TIX_ITEMNO on MY_TABLE(ITEM_NUMBER) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

I want to find the row in MY_TABLE where ITEM_NUMBER column is '1234.1234'

This does find the row:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%1234') > 0
```

This does not find the row:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%.1234') > 0
```

I do not understand why, since according to Oracle the dot is not a special character that has to be escaped.

How do I have to handle this situation?

Comment: What is the data what matches with the first and not the second?

Comment: Please show your sample input data running query against, and expected results.

Comment: You have no values of `text` that end in `'.1234'`.

Comment: Are you sure this is a text column?

Comment: ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,

Comment: Do you have a substring index on the column? Adding the DDL for the table and index(es) and sample data to the question might help.

Comment: CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
  (ITEM_NUMBER)
  VALUES
  ('1234.1234');

create index TIX_ITEMNO on MY_TABLE(ITEM_NUMBER)
  indextype is  ctxsys.context;

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%.1234') > 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your default lexer is treating the period as a word separator.

Initial setup:

```
create table my_table(item_number varchar2(50 byte) not null);

insert into my_table values ('1234.1234');

create index my_index on my_table (item_number) 
indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

This gets the behaviour you see:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%1234') > 0;

--------------------------------------------------
1234.1234

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%.1234') > 0;

no rows selected
```

If you add a lexer that defines [`PRINTJOINS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm#sthref476) to include the period:

```
drop index my_index;

begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER'); 
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_lexer', 'PRINTJOINS', '.');
end;
/

create index my_index on my_table (item_number) 
indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters ('lexer my_lexer');
```

then it behaves the way you want:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS(ITEM_NUMBER, '%.1234') > 0;

ITEM_NUMBER
--------------------------------------------------
1234.1234
```

[Read more about text indexing elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm).

Comment: Super explaination. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER like '%.1234'
```

Comment: Yes. It works with LIKE but I want to know why it does not work with CONTAINS.