# Oracle- need to use CONTAINS to find a string that contains a period

Tags: oracle, indexing, escaping, contains

I have a field in a table that is domain indexed so I can use CONTAINS in a query.  I am trying to create a query that can find an acronym (i.e. J.A.V.A.) exactly.  Problem is that the period '.' is a stopword that gets ignored.  I need to figure out how to do this by escaping the '.' somehow.  I can't find any reference online about how to do this, or maybe I am not fully understanding what I am reading.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(CLOB_column, '{J.A.V.A}')>0;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(CLOB_column, '{J_A_V_A_}')>0;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(CLOB_column, '{J\.A\.V\.A\.}')>0;
```

I created the domain index by:
    CREATE INDEX table_txt_idx ON table(CLOB_column) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;

I saw something (https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/full-text-indexing-using-oracle-text-9i) (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/csql.htm#CCREF0100) about appending to the index but I don't think it applies to a ctxsys index, but I am not fully sure.  I just know what I used didn't work.

```
BEGIN
  CTX_DLL.OPTIMIZE_INDEX('IDX_COLUMN_TXT','FAST');
END;
```

This didn't mention the ctxsys (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#BEIIEAFD)

I have created similar queries using LIKE and REGEXP_INSTR and need to create the same using CONTAINS so I can make sure I run the one that works the quickest.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE CLOB_column LIKE '%J.A.V.A.%';  --4.441 seconds

SELECT * from table WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(CLOB_column, '(J\.A\.V\.A\.)')>0; --23.528 seconds
```

Comment: Hi. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886431/10300113 . The whole answer is useful to you and it also contains a link to chapter 'punctuations' in 'Oracle Text Indexing Elements': https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm#sthref476

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query with wildcard and dot not matching data with Oracle Text index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885328/query-with-wildcard-and-dot-not-matching-data-with-oracle-text-index)

Comment: Great thread @Peter!  I wonder why I didn't find it?  Probably not using correct words in search.  Thanks!  I'll check this out and let you guys know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use [LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)?

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
( supplier_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL
 );

INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (5000, 'Apple');
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (5000, 'J.A.V.A');

SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name LIKE '%.%';
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name LIKE 'J.A.V.A';
```

Comment: No reason, just that I'm supposed to get it working in the most efficient manner and this is the only thing I haven't got working to compare yet.  So far on my sample table LIKE is the most efficient, but I would like to see if the CONTAINS is better due to the indexing.  It is something that will be run nightly along with other queries, so the quicker the better.